# Darcs installed with cabal not registered as shell command

Tags: haskell, cabal, darcs

As a part of installing Ubuntu on my computer, i `apt-get` installed `cabal`. After running `cabal update`, i ran `cabal install darcs`, discovered that i needed curses, installed `libncurses5-dev`, discovered that i needed curl, installed that, and when it still didn't work, ran `cabal install darcs -f-curl`.

This worked, but darcs doesn't run from the shell when just running `darcs`. It was installed in `~/.cabal/bin/darcs`, so i made a `link` from there to `/bin`. Darcs now works from the shell, but i am left wondering if there is a better way to do it, perhaps running `cabal install` under sudo?

Comment: Isn't there an Ubuntu package for darcs?

Comment: Yes, but it is several versions behind, and since darcs seems to be undergoing quite some development, i wanted to be sure that i got the newest release.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed as off topic – the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) explicitly covers questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers". I think `cabal` and `darcs` both fall under this remit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, do not use `sudo`. Even when run under root, `cabal` builds stuff in your home directory, so using `sudo` indiscriminately can lead to root-owned files in your `~/.cabal`. Instead, set `root-cmd: sudo` in your `/.cabal/config`, then `cabal` with the `--global` option will invoke that command as appropriate.

Secondly, using local installs is generally more convenient and safer than using global ones, because you keep your package manager and `cabal` separate. So you could just as well add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH
```

and then continue to install stuff without using `sudo` at all.

See also: a slightly over-pessimistic, but nevertheless informative [article on cabal package management](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/sicp.xhtml).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The article was a good read, but leaves me longing for having cabal be a fully fledged package manager.

Answer (score 6):

`cabal` by default installs without needing administrator privileges. As such, it can't install into e.g. `/usr/bin`. Since `$HOME/bin` isn't a standard, the compromise is to put executables into `~/.cabal/bin`.

You can then add `~/.cabal/bin` to your path to see these executables (e.g. by appending the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
 export $PATH=$PATH:~/.cabal/bin
```

If you have admin privledges in your machine, by all means use the `--global` flag.

Answer (score 1):

The `--global` flag is what is needed in this case. Running `sudo cabal install darcs -f-curl --global`, with `-f-curl` because cabal couldn't find curl, `--global` to make it install into `usr/local/bin`, and `sudo` just to be sure, works.

Comment: You'll probably find that the permissions in your `~/.cabal` directory are a mess now. They are easily fixed with `chown`, but it's a nuisance all the same.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the `chown` command. Works wonders!